# An exact sequence involving THH

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, equivariant-homotopy, hochschild-homology, long-exact-sequence

Disclaimer: I'm a relative beginner in this area. I'm trying to prove that if one has a commutative ring $R$ and a prime number $p$, then there is an exact sequence of the form
$$\DeclareMathOperator\THH{THH}
0 \rightarrow \pi_n(\THH(R)_{h\mathbb{T}})/p\pi_n(\THH(R)_{h\mathbb{T}}) \rightarrow \pi_n(\THH(R; \mathbb{F}_p)_{h\mathbb{T}}) \rightarrow \pi_{n-1}(\THH(R)_{h\mathbb{T}})[p] \rightarrow 0.
$$
My basic intuition is that arguing formally should go quite far. It would suffice to show that
$$
\THH(R)_{h\mathbb{T}} \xrightarrow{\times p} \THH(R)_{h\mathbb{T}} \rightarrow \THH(R; \mathbb{F}_p)_{h\mathbb{T}}
$$
is a fibration, for one could then take the long exact sequence in homotopy groups and then do some manipulations to quickly obtain the result. I'm not really sure how to show that one gets a fibration out of this however, or if one should take an entirely different approach. It does resemble the standard exact sequence one gets in the Bockstein spectral sequence, except $\THH(R)_{h\mathbb{T}}$ is far from needing to be torsion-free and that wouldn't help give a fibration anyway. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by $\DeclareMathOperator\THH{THH}\THH(R)_{h\mathbb T}\otimes\Bbb F_p$? A priori, the homotopy orbits $\THH(R)_{h\mathbb T}$ only has a spectrum structure (not being an object of $D(\mathbb Z)$), and the sequence that you wrote is not a fiber sequence.

Comment: I've clarified the question. I meant THH with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$. Miswrote it initially.

Comment: I don't even recognize what "THH" means. Maybe this could be stated just once in the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's extract a clear question (about spectra in general) from your question, and then answer it. Let $E$ be any spectrum.

There is the degree $p$ map $p:S\to S$ from the sphere spectrum to itself. Smashing with $E$, this gives a map $E\to E$; we also call this map $p$. It multiplies elements of $\pi_n(E)$ by $p$. Denote its spectrum cofiber by $E/pE$. The cofibration sequence $E\to E\to E/pE$ is also a fibration sequence, because we are talking about spectra. From the exact sequence
$$
\dots \to \pi_n(E)\to \pi_n(E)\to \pi_n(E/pE)\to \pi_{n-1}(E)\to \pi_{n-1}(E)\to \dots
$$
you get what I think you want: an exact sequence
$$
0\to coker(p)\to \pi_n(E/pE)\to ker(p)\to 0
$$
where the group on the left is
$$
coker (p:\pi_n(E)\to \pi_n(E))=\pi_n\otimes \mathbb F_p
$$
(it could also be called $\pi_n(E)/p$) and the group on the right is
$$
ker (p:\pi_{n-1}(E)\to \pi_{n-1}(E))=Tor(\pi_{n-1},\mathbb F_p)
$$
(I think you are also calling it $\pi_{n-1}(E)[p]$.)

$\pi_n(E/pE)$ is called the $n$th mod $p$ homotopy group of $E$.

Curiously, it can have elements of order $4$ if $p=2$.

Comment: Thanks for the very clear answer! It really clarified my thoughts. Is there some good intuition for why fiber and cofiber sequences coincide in spectra? What makes spectra special enough for this to happen?

Comment: I'm never quite sure of the best way to convey this to a beginner. To some extent the answer might depend on how you are thinking of spectra already.

I would say that in a sense this feature is the whole point of spectra. (Of course, that's not quite fair to say or historically accurate.) 

By the way, instead of "fiber and cofiber sequences coincide" one could focus on "pullback and pushout squares coincide", or "loopspace and suspension are inverse to one another".